# I'm using Magento 2.4.6 and want to allow customers to log in permanently as long as I don't hit the logout button

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4, customer-session, magento2.4.6

`I am trying to achieve a login duration of 2 days or (a period of time) for customers in Magento 2.4.6. I tried adjusting the "Online Session Lifetime" value to control the duration of customer sessions in Magento 2.4.6 but it's not working!`
[image]

Comment: "Online Session Lifetime" is no setting in magento. what do you mean? your screenshot shows the cookie lifetime. which is not the same as session

Answer (score 0):

If your customer session is not being established to do cookie settings then you should examine your php.ini file. Locate the **session.gc_maxlifetime parameter** and adjust its value accordingly. For instance, you can **set session.gc_maxlifetime to 86400**, or any other appropriate value.

Additionally, if you have a multi-store setup, ensure that you switch to the specific store and configure the cookie value for that store. To do so, navigate to **Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Cookie Settings -> Cookie Lifetime**.